# How get id of row in delete confirmation by modal bootstrap?

Tags: php, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone tell me what the best way to delete a row from a table in the bootstrap modal?

I've tried to pass the id of the row by javascript to a hidden field on a form, but did not succeed. I realized I was treating the onclick javascript function with php variables and mixing local and server activities.

I list the rows from table using php and I have submit the form in a modal, which I call via data attributes.

! [my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H43dk.png)

Comment: do you want to delete rows by php or js ?

Comment: php, delete rows of my table in server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use checkboxes to select the rows you want to delete, this assuming you have already fetched data from db:

```
<form action="" method="POST"  onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
<table>
<?php foreach($tables as $rows){ ?>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="<?php echo $rows['row_id'];?>">  </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then when the form is submitted you'll have all checked `ids` in `$_POST['delete']`. You can loop it and delete data.

Comment: The problem is that the submit to confirm deleting the id of the thread is modal. So I have to hold this information to send to the modal.

Comment: @AlexDoria see the change please